# What do I do if my minecraft doesnt ask for a password?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have just recently purchased minecraft, I downloaded the launcher for windows, and it isnt asking for a password, just the account. Please Help :(

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Just to be sure… did you buy it and download it from [`minecraft.net`](http://minecraft.net)?

Comment: You are using the proper loader and not something like MinecraftSP?

Comment: You probably downloaded a "crack" launcher, a version that allows you to play with only a username, for people who haven't paid the game. However, from a legal point of view, this version is illegal, because it provides a copy of the game that doesn't "comes from" Mojang, so you should not use it (unless you bought a copy of the game), and download the [official launcher](http://minecraft.net/download) from Minecraft.net. You can recognize the unofficial launchers by looking at their names (MinecraftSP) or their UI (a gray box at the center, w/o any other informations).

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're using the [official client](http://minecraft.net/download), you need to put your login details here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's not asking for a password, perhaps there's an issue with your java cache. [Here's an article on how to clear it.](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml)

If that doesn't work, try re-installing java altogether.